# Как правильно перенаправить страницы с HTTPS на HTTP в apache2?

Tags: apache2, редирект

У меня на сайте все страницы перенаправляются с http на https. Но мне нужно, чтобы некоторые страницы (link на все картины) остались на http. Как это можно сделать?

```
RewriteBase /

Options +Indexes 
# or #
IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^style/style[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.css$ style/style.css [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^scripts[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.js$ scripts.js [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3&fourth=$4&fifth=$5&sixth=$6 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3&fourth=$4&fifth=$5&sixth=$6 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3&fourth=$4&fifth=$5 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3&fourth=$4&fifth=$5 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3&fourth=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3&fourth=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ну, как говорится, "щенка с таким именем ждут во дворе одни неприятности". В смысле, браузер будет помечать SSL-сайт как подозрительный, если в нем часть ссылок осталась на HTTP. Если это не смущает, то нужно усовершенствовать правило для mod_rewrite, которым у Вас осуществляется переписывание URL'ей, если, конечно, используется данный модуль. Если Вы приведете пример того, каким образом осуществлено перенаправление и покажете, какие URL'ы надо оставить неизменными, будет проще дать точный ответ.

Comment: RewriteBase /
Options +Indexes 
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^style/style[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.css$ style/style.css [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^scripts[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.js$ scripts.js [L,QSA]

Comment: Пример URL который надо оставить неизменным: http://example.com/thumbs/image.jpg, то есть все ссылки на картинок.

Comment: лучше б прямо вопрос отредактировать, в комментариях форматирование не сохраняется